# How to separately display description and the image from article in module joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I tried to display article image and description in another module in joomla. It like wordpress posts.

Here i want to display product name,Image and the description.
So i took the title as the product name and now i want to divide introtext into two parts as image and description which article have.

I have post for every products which category id = 9.

This is the Code i used

```
<?php
catID = 9;
//echo $catID;
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$page_title = $doc->getTitle();
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT title, introtext FROM #__content WHERE catid = ".$catID);
$articles = $db->loadObjectList(); ?> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="nopadding">
    <?php foreach($articles as $article){
$title = $article->title;?>
<!-- Image -->
<!-- Description -->
        <img class="ras-img" src=""><!-- Image should add here -->
        <div class="ras-hvr">
            <div class="ras-inner-hvr">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6  pro-name"><?php echo $article->title; ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12  pro-des"><!-- Description here --></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please add more information about the problem? As for article image please check my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25842122/3834042.

Comment: First, you absolutely should not be doing a query in an article layout. If nothing else, use a plugin to get the data.  When you say "module" do you mean Joomla module or do you mean a component?  Just echo your image data where ever you and it, just like in the core layouts for articles or article intros (like in the blog layouts).  Also use the Joomla api for your query.  It's really quite unclear what you are doing an why it would require more than a layout override.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php`
near the top you'll see this line of code to set `$images`.

```
$images  = json_decode($this->item->images);
```

Further down, you'll see how the image is displayed:

```
<?php if (isset($images->image_fulltext) && !empty($images->image_fulltext)) : ?>
<?php $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_fulltext)) ? $params->get('float_fulltext') : $images->float_fulltext; ?>
<div class="pull-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?> item-image"> <img
<?php if ($images->image_fulltext_caption):
    echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_caption) . '"';
endif; ?>
src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_alt); ?>"/> </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For description:

```
$title = $article->introtext;   and/or   $title = $article->fulltext;
```

Now, with that information, you need to create a template override so that you don't hack the core installation files.  See [How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for details, but essentially, you do this using your template (I'll use beez3 for the example):

1. Create folder `\templates\beez3\html\com_content\article`
2. Into that folder, ***copy*** `\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php`
3. Make your layout changes to the *copied* php file
4. Joomla will look for it and load it from there if it exists instead of the core file.